# How to start minimized ClickOnce application on Windows startup?

Tags: c#, wpf, clickonce, startup

I'd usually set some command line arguments to the application which I want to start minimized on Windows startup, but a ClickOnce application does not accept parameters when you launch it through an application-reference shortcut.

Is there aother way to make an application start minimized? Starting the application by URL (with URL parameters) is not an option for me, because there's no guarantee that user will have an Internet connection on Windows startup.

It's a [WPF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Presentation_Foundation) application. To make the application start with Windows, I put a registry key to the application-reference as described in *[ClickOnce and startup on Windows logon (Vista)](http://dipeshavlani.net/2009/05/12/clickonce-and-startup-on-windows-logon-vista/)*.

Comment: Not sure what magic solution you're looking for.  Here's one: set the main Window's WindowState to "Minimized" in the designer.

Comment: But then it would start minimized even if you manually launch application. It should run minimized to tray only on windows startup.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As long as you are using at least .NET 3.5 **SP1** you can pass parameters to the app-ref shortcut, see *[How to pass arguments to an offline ClickOnce application](http://robindotnet.wordpress.com/2010/03/21/how-to-pass-arguments-to-an-offline-clickonce-application/)* or if that's TL;DR see [ClickOnce appref.ms argument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/558344/clickonce-appref-ms-argument)